# How to find percent overlap between coordinates in each row from two files in awk

Tags: awk, compare

I have fileA in the below format:

```
ID      Start      End             NUM         Length
ID3    80203644    80329880        num=12     length=126,237      
ID3    82010803    82148878        num=13     length=138,076 
ID8    10367405    10471540        num=6      length=104,136  
ID8    75329673    75843153        num=34     length=513,481  
ID9    39541656    39712888        num=14     length=171,233
```

And fileB in the below format

```
 ID     Start       End         X         Y
ID3    80242334    80342344    189196   578.99
ID3    57671687    57671747    187531   149.05
ID8    75309673    75823153    5646     4535.05
ID9    39551656    39732888    374767   4398.08
```

Using column 1 as a key i.e. comparing the rows in fileA with ID in column 1 with rows in fileB having same ID in column 1 in fileB. I would like to compare fileA with file B to check: if the numbers in column 2 and column 3 in fileA overlap with the coordinates in column 2 and column  3 in fileB.

Sample output:

```
   ID     Start       End         X         Y       OverlapStart   OverlapEnd
  ID3      80242334    80342344    189196   578.99  80242334  80329880 
  ID3      57671687    57671747    187531   149.05     -        -
  ID8    75309673    75823153    5646     4535.05    75329673  75823153
  ID9    39541656    39712888    374767   4398.08    39541656  39712888
```

And write the rows in fileA that do not overlap to a separate file. In this example it will be:

```
 ID      Start      End             NUM         Length     
 ID3    82010803    82148878        num=13     length=138,076 
 ID8    10367405    10471540        num=6      length=104,136
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start using GNU awk 4.* for true multi-D arrays and sorted `in` operator:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    sta=2; end=3
}
{ recs[ARGIND][$1][++cnt[ARGIND][$1]] = $0 }
(NR!=FNR) && (FNR>1) {
    split($0,fileA)
    for (unq in recs[1][$1]) {
        split(recs[1][$1][unq],fileB)
        if ( ( (fileA[sta] > fileB[sta]) && (fileA[sta] < fileB[end]) ) ||
             ( (fileA[end] > fileB[sta]) && (fileA[end] < fileB[end]) ) ) {
            print "overlap:", $0
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (fileNr=1;fileNr<=ARGIND;fileNr++) {
        printf "\nHere are the contents of %s:\n", ARGV[fileNr]
        for (key in recs[fileNr]) {
            for (unq in recs[fileNr][key]) {
                print key, unq, recs[fileNr][key][unq]
            }
        }
    }

}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk fileB fileA
overlap: ID3    80203644    80329880        num=12     length=126,237
overlap: ID8    75329673    75843153        num=34     length=513,481
overlap: ID9    39541656    39712888        num=14     length=171,233

Here are the contents of fileB:
ID 1  ID     Start       End         X         Y
ID3 1 ID3    80242334    80342344    189196   578.99
ID3 2 ID3    57671687    57671747    187531   149.05
ID8 1 ID8    75309673    75823153    5646     4535.05
ID9 1 ID9    39551656    39732888    374767   4398.08

Here are the contents of fileA:
ID 1 ID      Start      End             NUM         Length
ID3 1 ID3    80203644    80329880        num=12     length=126,237
ID3 2 ID3    82010803    82148878        num=13     length=138,076
ID8 1 ID8    10367405    10471540        num=6      length=104,136
ID8 2 ID8    75329673    75843153        num=34     length=513,481
ID9 1 ID9    39541656    39712888        num=14     length=171,233
```

From there it's just a matter of adding a small amount of extra logic to print whatever you like to wherever you like when overlaps do/don't occur. The prints in the END section are just to show you how to loop through the file contents stored in each array. Good luck!

Comment: I understand that the if condition is looking  only for a complete overlap i.e. for fileA ranges within FileB ranges. Isn't it?  If yes, could it be possible so that fileA ranges can be in file B ranges or fileB ranges can be in fileA ranges or fileA ranges can be partially in fileB ranges. However, the output should be from file A.

Comment: a) No, it's looking for the start or end point of A being within the start/end range of B. b) Sure, just code whatever condition you like following the pattern in the above script. c) The output IS from file A so Idk what that means but if you want to compare B against A instead of what you said (`I would like to compare fileA with file B`) then just switch the order of the files and change the variable names. d) I show you in the END how to access all fields of both files - you really should be able to figure out anything you want to do given that.